# How to load strut slide editor for impress.js in offline mode

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, html, webserver

I have downloaded strut editor from https://github.com/tantaman/Strut

But in offline mode the index.html is not loading the editor. How to Open the editor?
From app folder I run the index.html but it does not show anything

Answer (score 1):

The main page of Strut IO (https://github.com/tantaman/Strut) project leads us to **Development/Building** section.

```
To build your own version of Strut you'll need Grunt v0.4.0 or later.
 1. Install the latest Grunt: npm install -g grunt-cli
 2. Clone Strut: git clone git://github.com/tantaman/Strut.git
 3. cd Strut
 4. Install Strut's development dependencies: npm install
 5. Run Strut: grunt server (the server runs at localhost:9000)
To make a production build of Strut run grunt build. The resulting build will be located in Strut/dist
```

Answer (score 0):

Vadik Smirnov gave you the solution, but I suppose that he forgot (probably he assumed that) to say that all the operations must be executed in the GitHub Shell.

1. Install "GitHub Desktop" https://desktop.github.com/
2. Register or sign in with your account
3. Open Git shell from the menu

Now follow the commands suggested by Vadik Smirnov.

Answer (score 0):

I created a docker container with `strut`. You can run it out of the box with:

```
docker run -d -p 9000:9000 silgon/strut
```

Then you can access it within your localhost with the following url:

```
http://localhost:9000
```

Also, if you want to see the instructions for installation you can follow the ones on the [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/silgon/dockerfiles/blob/strut_v1/strut/Dockerfile) of the my git repository.